# turn a number into an array of integers up to that number starting from 1

Tags: arrays, ruby

So I am trying to turn a number into an array of integers up to that number starting at one. So for example if the number is `9` I want an array to be `nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]` Is there any built-in method for this? I try the following:

```
 arr = [] 
(1..9).each do |num|   
  arr << num 
end
```

But this gives me the following output.
`arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

Comment: Your code is correct, when I execute your sample I have the expected output : `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

Comment: I as well don't see how you could get a 0 in your array given that range.

Answer (score 4):

Using the `..` operator creates a Range, and Per the [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Range.html), a Range, like any other Enumerable object, can be converted directly into an Array:

```
(1..9).to_a
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

You might be interested to know that you can also do this with a Range built using String values:

```
('a'..'e').to_a
#=> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
```

Comment: or dates for example in `ActiveRecord` something like `(Date.today.at_beginning_of_month..Date.today).to_a`

Comment: Yep. Also works intelligently with longer strings like `('model_101'..'model_105').to_a`

Answer (score 2):

```
num = 9
(1..num).to_a
# => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

or

```
Array(1..num)
```

Answer (score 2):

A neat [trick](https://youtu.be/gIEMKOI_Y-4?t=15m37s):

```
[*1..9]
 #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

And as we're in Ruby land, some alternatives:

```
Array.new 9 { |i| i + 1 }
 #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

9.times.with_object [] { |i,o| o << i + 1 }
 #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

(1..Float::INFINITY).take 9
 #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: I'd go with `n.downto(1).to_a.reverse`.

Comment: @SebastiánPalma or to avoid reversing, `1.upto(9).to_a`:)

Comment: Maybe `(49.."#{n}".ord).map { |e| e.chr.to_i }`?

Comment: While we're at it, why not `'123456789'.chars.map(&:to_i)`? :)

Comment: Since we are having so much fun `Enumerator.new {|y| i = 0; loop { y << i+=1}}.first(9)`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it:

```
(1..9).map(&:itself)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
(1..x).to_a
```

Where `x` can be any number.

Comment: He says *_from 1 to x*